# Cython- import class to pyx file

Tags: python, cython, cimport

For example let's say we have two classe,

**Bus**- *Implement The physical bus line.*

src/bus/bus.pxd

```
   cdef class Bus:
        cdef int get_item(self)
```

src/bus/bus.pxd:

```
cdef class Bus: 
    cdef int get_item(self):
        return 5
```

**CPU**- *Implement The physical cpu processor*

src/cpu/cpu.pyx:

```
cimport bus.Bus as Bus
cdef class Cpu:
     cdef Bus bus
     cdef __cinit__(self, Bus bus):
         self.bus = bus
```

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
import sys
import numpy 

USE_CYTHON = False

files = [
    ('src.bus', 'src/bus/bus'),
    ('src.cpu', 'src/cpu/cpu'),
] 

if '--use-cython' in sys.argv:
    USE_CYTHON = True
    sys.argv.remove('--use-cython')
   
ext = '.pyx' if USE_CYTHON else '.c'


extensions = []
for package_path, file_path in files:
    extensions.append(
        Extension(package_path,[f"{file_path}{ext}"],
                        language='c',
                        include_dirs=['src/c/'])
    )

if USE_CYTHON:
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
    extensions = cythonize(extensions)

setup(
    ext_modules=extensions,
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
)
```

However, when compiling this example the compiler raise error of `'Bus' is not a type identifier`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

So, in cython we've to use pxd file for declaration in compile time.
Therefor, adding `__init__.pxd` have to bee added for compilation import.
In Addition, I've created `cpu.pxd` file which inside I've wrote `from bus cimport Bus`.

Comment: The only problem with your example is that, in the `src/cpu/cpu.pyx` file, you are writing `cimport bus.Bus as Bus` instead of `cimport bus.bus.Bus as Bus`. There is no need to create extra files such as `__init__.pxd`, or `src/cpu/cpu.pxd`.